# With KableExtra in Xaringan how can I remove the space between columns

Tags: r, kableextra, xaringan

I am trying to replicate a table from a book on a `xaringan` slide using `kableExtra`.  The table in the book has solid horizontal lines.  I can get close but there is a white space (guessing 1 px) between the columns which is breaking the solid line into chunks.  How can I remove that white space?

Here is the example:

````
---
title: "White pixel..."
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---

```{css, echo=F}
    .remark-slide thead, .remark-slide tr:nth-child(2n) {
        background-color: white;
    }
```

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
suppressMessages(library(tidyr))
table2_1 <- data.frame(Gender = c("Female", "Female", "Male", "Male"), 
                       Belief = c(" Yes", "No", " Yes", "No"),
                       Count = c(1230, 357, 859, 413))

wide <- 
  xtabs(Count ~ Gender + Belief, table2_1) %>% 
  addmargins() %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  pivot_wider(id = Gender, names_from = Belief, values_from = n) 

library(kableExtra)
wide %>% 
  kbl() %>% 
  add_header_above(c(" ", "Belief in Afterlife" = 2, " ")) %>% 
  kableExtra::row_spec(0, extra_css = "border-bottom: 1px solid") 
  
```
````

Comment: Very interesting, I think, that is a bug(?). With other table, f.e. ```head(mtcars[1:5]) %>%
kbl() %>%  kable_styling() ``` we have same situation. Maybe you'll ask on Github?